# corecursion and codata

Tags: haskell

Would like to get step-by-step explanation of the following function in Haskell

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

I understand that the "fibs" in general is "lazy", so next item would be calculated "on demand", however I'm not sure how the "tail" function would work on infinite list.

So the illustration of how it works with some intermediate data would help.

Comment: Tail is to get the rest of the list after 1st element and hence there is no problem in making it lazy as we don't need to calculate the actual list after 1st item.. just 1st item needs to be evaluated

Comment: If I may ask, what exactly do "corecursion" and "codata" mean?

Comment: Dan, he probably got this off the Wikipedia corecursion/coinduction articles

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the beginning, the evalution is like this:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

If we replace `fibs` by its evaluation, it looks like this:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) (0 : 1 : ?) (1 : ?)
```

Where `?` denotes the unevaluated thunk. Let's evaluate the next element of `fibs`:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) (0 : 1 : ?) (1 : ?) ==>
fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) (1 : ?) (?)
```

The first element of each of the argument lists of `zipWith` is consumed. Now, when we evaluated it, we also know, what the value of the next thunk is and we can fill it in. That allows us to evaluate the next cell, and so on:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) (1 : ?) (?) ==>
fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) (1 : 1 : ?) (1 : ?) ==>
fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : zipWith (+) (1 : ?) (?) ==>
fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : zipWith (+) (1 : 2 : ?) (2 : ?) ==>
fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : zipWith (+) (2 : ?) (?) ==>
...
```

Comment: Is that `?` a mutable variable? ;)

Comment: @missigno I would call it "universal replacement for something we don't know yet."

Comment: @missingno: it's a thunk.  In a running Haskell program, all data is either an actual value, or a computation which can be run to compute the value; this computation is called a thunk.  I'd recommend Edward Yang's blog series about the Haskell heap for more on this topic: http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/04/the-haskell-heap/

Answer (score 2):

`tail` on an infinite list is very simple: generate the first argument if necessary, then throw it away.

So

```
fibs       =  0 : 1 : fibs'
tail fibs  =      1 : fibs'
```

and

```
tail fibs         =  1 : 1 : fibs''
tail (tail fibs)  =      1 : fibs''
```

and

```
tail (tail fibs)         =  1 : 2 : fibs'''
tail (tail (tail fibs))  =      2 : fibs'''
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the back end:

- `tail` returns the content of a list wihtout the head, e.g. `tail [1,2,3]` --> `[2,3]`
- `zipWith` applies a function pair-wise on the contents of two lists, e.g. `zipWith (+) [1,2] [10,20]` --> `[11,22]`
- `fibs` is defined as a list which starts with 0 and 1, and then the result of the `zipWith` operation

Here is a schema that explains what's going on in zipWith

```
       v-searching the third value of fibs
fibs: [0,1,...]
tail: [1,.....]
--------------
sum:  [1,.....]

now fibs is sum together with the leading 0 and 1:

         v-searching the fourth value of fibs
fibs: [0,1,1,.....]
tail: [1,1,.......]
-------------------
sum:  [1,2,.......] 

now fibs is sum together with the leading 0 and 1:

           v-searching the fifth value of fibs
fibs: [0,1,1,2,.....] 
tail: [1,1,2,.......] 
----------------------
sum:  [1,2,3,.......] 

now fibs is sum together with the leading 0 and 1:

             v-searching the sixth value of fibs
fibs: [0,1,1,2,3,.....] 
tail: [1,1,2,3,.......] 
------------------------
sum:  [1,2,3,5,.......]
```

So you can see that you can derive the whole list if you act "step by step", which is possible because of Haskell's lazy behavior.

Comment: Does it mean that zipwith is executed on all already calculated items from the fibs list for each new number?

Comment: @jdevelop zipWith is executed as the results are needed.  E.g., when printing fibs.